# What is the best way to move Cassandra cluster form AWS to GoogleCloud

Tags: cassandra, datastax, data-migration

We have a cluster of Cassandra consists of two datacenters one of them on AWS and the other on our on-premises servers.

The cluster is running with DSE 5.0 and we need to move the AWS dc to GoogleCloud and upgrade the cluster to DSE 5.1.

Can I create a new dc in Google with the DSE 5.1 and join it with the current cluster which is running DSE 5.0 then shutdown the AWS dc after the data transferred to new dc?

Or create a new cluster on Google then transfer the data manually from AWS to Google then format the on premises then join it to the new cluster on Google?

Or there are other solutions?

Thanks for help

Comment: it's better to ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/, for example

Comment: There are several ways to move to a different cloud provider, but you can never run a mixed version DSE environment. When you do get situated on the new cloud and want to upgrade to DSE 5.1 make sure to go through any DSE5.0 patches before moving to DSE5.1 and make sure all nodes are the same version and patch release.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new DC in GoogleCloud (DSE 5.0, don't mix different version during transition, schema change, topology change) , join the existing cluster, run repair and then shutdown AWS DC. You need to make sure you have connectivity between all DC during this transition. This approach allows availability of existing DCs and phased transition of application from AWS to Google DC.
Avoid upgrading to DSE 5.1 during this transition.